# Как узнать количество передаваемых значений в varArg

Tags: java

Работаю с объектами, которые хочу засунуть в масив.
Создал отдельный метод в который передам не знаю сколько значений.
Размер массива хочу сделать равным количеству передаваемых значений.
Как получить количество переданныхв метод значений?

```
public class ElectricityCount {
    private ElectronicUnit[] units;

    public String toGroupUnits(ElectronicUnit ... var){
        units = new ElectronicUnit[/*тут должно быть значение из передаваемых значений*/ ]
        for(int i=0;i<  /*тут должно быть значение из передаваемых значений*/ ;i++){
            units[i]=var;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша переменная `var` - это обычный массив.
Соответственно в свойстве `length` будет лежать его размер:

```
var.length;
```

И ваш метод тогда будет таким:

```
public void toGroupUnits(ElectronicUnit ... var){
    units = new ElectronicUnit[var.length]
    for(int i = 0; i < var.length; i++){
        units[i] = var[i];
    }
}
```

Кстати, всю эту конструкцию можно заменить вызовом `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
public void toGroupUnits(ElectronicUnit ... var){
    units = Arrays.copyOf(var, var.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно без узнавания количества просто итерировать по каждому значению:

```
for (ElectronicUnit eu: var) {
    code here
}
```